# Web Deploy 2.0 - Possible to prevent debug deploy?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, web-deployment, web-deployment-project, webdeploy

When developing an ASP.NET website with the Entity Framework, you can use an initialiser to drop and recreate the database when the model changes.

Take this example:
I set up my project to drop and recreate the db under the Debug configuration, but not the Release.

I use Web Deploy 2.0, but, I see a potential issue, where I deploy to a production server, and forget to build the website with the configuration set to Release. Therefore the db may be dropped in production.

Is there a way to prohibit Visual Studio from publishing a website, based on certain criteria? e.g.   destination server is X and the project is built in the Debug configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you know the server name, you can write code to skip setting the database initializer in Global.asax

```
if(Server.MachineName=="skipServerName")
{//do not set the initalizer
}
```

Comment: Tks for the first idea, I'd mark this as useful if I had the reputation.